# Hive permission denied error when connected from spark

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hive

I'm connecting to Hive metastore from Spark and executing a "create external table" statement. I get this error

> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException:
>   MetaException(message:java.security.AccessControlException: Permission
>   denied: user=hive, access=WRITE,
>   inode="/user/mike/test":mike:users:drwxr-xr-x

Hive impersonation is set to true in hive-site.xml

> hive.server2.enable.doAs = true

But still error occurs. How to fix this? This is my code snippet and I'm executing it from the user 'mike'

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="PythonSQL")
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
sqlContext.sql("create external table ... location '/user/mike/test')
```

Comment: Please check the owner permissions for the hive and the folder in that error you mentioned using the command ls -la, if its not hadoop, provide the permission by using sudo chown -R........ command

Comment: The problem is spark connecting to hive using 'hive' user, where it should be connecting as the user who is running the spark application

Comment: could you try this command "hadoop fs -chmod 777 /user/mike/test" and re-execute your work and check pls

Comment: in case if the above command doesn't work pls try this command "sudo chown -R USERNAME:hadoop  /user/mike/test" in my case the USERNAME is hduser so my command would be like  "sudo chown -R hduser:hadoop /user/mike/test"

Comment: It is working fine after granting write permission to all users to the folder /user/mike/test. I am executing the spark application from mike user account. But spark is connecting to hive as 'hive' user instead of 'mike'. mike user has read and write access to /user/mike/test folder, but hive user does not. That is the problem. How to connect to hive from spark as the user executing the spark application?

Comment: Sorry actually, I don't have much knowledge about spark but, I too faced the same type of error while connecting to HIVE & R-Language so it became easy for me to identify the problem and provide the solution. If my answer is helpful to you please upvote to my comment so that it would help me "Thank you".

Comment: Also I noticed that the owner of the created hive table is 'mike'. But to access the file in the hdfs it was using the 'hive' user which did not have privileges to that folder.